# Historical present-''I remember how

Tags: grammar, tense-agreement

Is this sentence correct when I am narrating a past event using the present tense (**historical present**)

> "I *remember the first time* I **spoke** to a hot girl (English native speaker), it **was** completely intimidating, my mind **was** kinda feeling numb, and while she **was** talking, I **was** concurrently self-talking saying 'is this really happening? Is this really happening?!''

My introductory clause is in present tense (**I remember the first time**), then followed by past tenses as I go on storytelling. Did I do correctly?

Comment: If you are remembering it in the present, it is OK. And "is this really happening" is OK as reported speech.

Comment: Your sentence does not use the historic present. You need to replace instances of **was** with **is** or **am** and adjust **spoke** accordingly. The meaning of *concurrently self-talking* is not clear. Do you mean that you were talking to yourself?

Comment: @RonaldSole, yeah my bad about the tenses pertaining the historic present thingy, but I did some present tenses there right. While 'concurrently' is the same as what you are asking, you have just rephrased it the other way around, I think 'concurrently' is used correctly here without a sense of ambiguity-why would you say it wasn't clear?

Comment: Of course, you remember now what happened **then**. But the next bit might read better as: I was saying to myself "Is this really happening. Is this **really happening**?". [that should be simple italics but I don't know how to do it.]

Comment: @JohnArvin Although this site is about correct English rather than good English, it's a delight to read something elegant and a pain to struggle through cumbersome constructions. **Concurrently** is redundant. You've already said that she was talking while you were talking. And the expression **concurrently self-talking** sounds as though you chose words from a lottery list. It's clumsy, awkward and overwritten. I accept that this is just my opinion. I can only add that I marked a lot of essays - and wrote a lot of reports in my time for taskmasters much tougher than myself.

Comment: @RonaldSole, yeah you're right, the ''while''+''concurrently'' made it obviously redundant. Moreover, I just learned it from non-native, though I had gut feeling that it would sound taken from a very distant past, I still used it here wahehe, should be simpler right, I got you man, that's my last use I suppose.

Comment: @JohnArvin Last thing on my mind was to discourage you. Keep writing. Keep it simple while you build up your skills.You'll get better every day!

Comment: @RonaldSole, wow that's 'golden' advice for me, thx man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection between the main verb "remember" and the relative clause's verb (speak), which indicates that "speak" can be used in the past tense form if it is necessary.

> I remember [the first time **when I spoke to a hot girl**].("*When*" can be omitted)
>
> I remember [*when I first spoke to a hot girl*].

They are both the same.